# Is there a way to get all the emails of users in a GSuite using GMail API?

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-imap

How to get the emails of users within a GSuite organization similar to
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id ?

Comment: Whats wrong with using that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Google PHP SDK, you can do something like this.

```
$dir = 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='service-account.json';
        putenv("$dir");
        // var_dump($dir);
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias'));
        $client->setSubject("$this->admin_email");
        $dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
        $users = $dir->users->listUsers(Array('domain' => "your-super@admin-email.com");

foreach ($users["users"] as $key => $value) {
                $email = $value['primaryEmail'];
                $name = $value['name']['fullName'];
                foreach ($value["emails"] as $key => $email_alias) {
                    $alias = $email_alias['address'];
                    $users[] = ["email" => $email,
                                "alias" => $alias,
                                "name" => $name
                                ];
                }

            }
            print_r($users);
```

You will need to make sure that you have granted permission to your GSuite app. More information at my blog here on how to do this if you're unsure.

http://moometric.com/integrations/gsuite/use-gmail-api-update-signatures-gsuite-users-php/